# fastboot check password failed

Tags: rooting, fastboot

I try to unlock OEM, using command `fastboot oem unlock`. My device is **Huawei MediaPad Т5** *tablet*. I got the error:

```
...
FAILED (remote: check password failed!)
finished. total time: 0.014s
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a unlock code from Huawei. Unfortunately they do not provide unlock codes anymore. Your only chance is buy one from third party seller